# Regex: match two adjacent strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some code such as:

```
if('hello' == 2 && 'world' !== -1){
  return true;
}
```

I'm having some trouble matching the condition in the `if` statement. The first regex I thought of was `/'.*'/`, but this matches:

1. 'hello'
2. ' == 2 && '
3. 'world'

which isn't what I was hoping for. I only want to match the single quotes and the text inside.

1. 'hello'
2. 'world'

Any body have any idea?

Comment: PHP isn't a _regular_ language. Using regular expressions to parse it is per definition the wrong choice.

Comment: PHP has a tokenizer for itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727951/what-are-some-practical-uses-of-php-tokenizer and http://php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php. **USE IT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
preg_match_all('/\'[^\'\r\n]*\'/m', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```

**Explanation**

```
"
'           # Match the character “'” literally
[^'\\r\\n]    # Match a single character NOT present in the list below
               # The character “'”
               # A carriage return character
               # A line feed character
   *           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
'           # Match the character “'” literally
"
```

Answer (score 0):

The two matching groups int this should pick up your quoted values:

```
^.*(\'.*?\').*(\'.*?\').*$
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case

```
\'[a-z]*?\'
```

For the entire code, if you have uppercase characters in the quotes, you can use

```
\'[a-zA-Z]*?\'
```

However, if you have special characters in the quotes as well, then you can use what @Chris Cooper suggested. Depending on your need, there are a variety of answers possible.

Note: '?' after * makes * non-greedy, so it wont try to search till the last quote.

It also matters which regex method you use to get the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with!

```
preg_match_all("#'[^'\n\r]*'#", $subject, $matches);
```

1. Match `'`.
2. Match any character that is not `'`, new line, or carriage return.
3. Match `'`.

Without all of the escaping, I think it's a bit more readable—for being a regular expression, anyway.